# Change Leaflet marker icon with data from external geoJSON file

Tags: javascript, leaflet, icons, geojson, marker

I have a problem at changing the icons of my geoJSON data on my Leaflet map.

I'm loading my data from external geoJSON files. Therefore I'm using a `XMLHttpRequest()` to open the files (filenames are stored in an array `orteDB`) and then add them to my layer `orte` where it's then added to the map:

```
for (var i = 0; i < orteDB.length; i++) {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'files/geoJSONfiles/orte/' + orteDB[i]);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (xhr.status !== 200) return
        L.geoJSON(xhr.response).addTo(orte).on('click', onClick);
    };
    xhr.send();
}

orte = L.geoJson(orte).addTo(map);
```

I already managed to change the default icon with the help of this example https://gist.github.com/geog4046instructor/80ee78db60862ede74eacba220809b64. But what I actually want is the icon to change dynamically after the click of a button or the marker itself to this `redIcon`:

```
var redIcon = L.Icon.extend({
        iconUrl: 'files/marker-icon_red.png',
        iconSize:     [25, 41],
        iconAnchor:   [12, 40],
    });
```

I also tried working with the `pointToLayer()` function but it didn't work for me.

Each geoJSON point has a unique ID which I can call via `e.layer.feature.properties.id`. So in the end I'd like to change the marker icon individually by using it's unique ID.

My geoGSON files look like this:

```
{
 "type": "FeatureCollection",
 "name": "02_Roncesvalles",
 "features": [
  { 
   "type": "Feature", 
   "properties": 
     { 
      "id": 2 }, 
   "geometry": 
     { 
      "type":"Point", 
      "coordinates": [ 
        -1.320700314538876, 
        43.009378247303687 ] 
     } 
   }
  ]
}
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the icon of a marker with `marker.setIcon(icon)` and you need to loop through all layers and find the correct one over the id.

I use `map.eachLayer` instead of `orte.eachLayer()` because the GeoJSON Group can also contains LayerGroups.

```
var wantedId = 1;
map.eachLayer((layer)=>{
   if(layer instanceof L.Marker && layer.feature && layer.feature.properties && layer.feature.properties.id == wantedId){
      layer.setIcon(new redIcon());
   }
});
```

**Update**

Thx to @ghybs, I didn't recognice the `extend` of the icon.

If you want to extend the icon class you need to put the options in a `options` property.

```
var redIcon = L.Icon.extend({
   options: {
        iconUrl: 'files/marker-icon_red.png',
        iconSize:     [25, 41],
        iconAnchor:   [12, 40],
   }
});
```

And then you can change the Icon with `marker.setIcon(new redIcon())`

But I suggest you to simply create a Icon variable instead of creating a new class.

```
var redIcon = L.icon({
        iconUrl: 'files/marker-icon_red.png',
        iconSize:     [25, 41],
        iconAnchor:   [12, 40],
    });
```

And then call `marker.setIcon(redIcon)`

Comment: Thanks for your help! When I try it, I always get `Uncaught TypeError: layer.setIcon is not a function`. Do you know why that may be?

Comment: @ELonMask: you very probably have non Point type features in your GeoJSON data. Sharing a representative sample of your data would help providing a more relevant answer.

Comment: @ELonMask I added `layer instanceof L.Marker` to the if, then it should work

Comment: @FalkeDesign Thank you. Unfortunately `layer instanceof L.Marker` does not work, I now get the error `t.icon.createIcon is not a function`. 
@ghybs I added an example of my geoJSON files. I think it's not really recognized as a marker/point so it won't change the icon.

Comment: @ELonMask look into this example: https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/n5veb63L/ it is working like I described

Comment: @FalkeDesign: OP extends the Icon class as in https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/#defining-an-icon-class, so you need to instantiate it first.

Comment: Nice, it's now working. Thanks very much!